# How to add ListStore inside ListStore in Rust's gtk-rs bindings?

Tags: combobox, rust, gtk3, treemodel, rust-gnome

I want to create program with a `TreeView` containing `ComboBox`es using the [gtk-rs bindings](http://gtk-rs.org/).

In order to have data for the `GtkCellRendererCombo`, I need a `GtkTreeModel *`, but I don't know how to add a `ListStore` inside a `ListStore`.

For now I have only a simple `TreeView`. I want a `ComboBox` inside 1 column (header "f64"):

```
extern crate gtk;

use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::{ComboBox, ListStore, Orientation, TreeView, TreeViewColumn, Window, WindowType};

fn main() {
    gtk::init().expect("Failed to initialize GTK");
    let window = Window::new(WindowType::Toplevel);
    window.set_position(gtk::WindowPosition::Center);
    window.set_title("Rust&GTK+3");
    window.set_position(gtk::WindowPosition::Center);
    window.connect_delete_event(|wind, _| {
        let (szerokosc, wysokosc) = wind.get_size();
        println!("Width {} Height {}", szerokosc, wysokosc);
        // Stop the main loop.
        gtk::main_quit();
        // Let the default handler destroy the window.
        Inhibit(false)
    });
    let main_box = gtk::Box::new(Orientation::Vertical, 0);
    let view_list = TreeView::new();
    {
        let types_inside_columns = &[gtk::Type::U32, gtk::Type::F64];
        let model_list_of_data = ListStore::new(types_inside_columns);
        for liczba in 0..10 {
            let array_of_data = [&(liczba.to_value()) as &ToValue,
                                 &((liczba as f64 * 1.5).to_value()) as &ToValue];
            model_list_of_data.insert_with_values(None, &[0, 1], &array_of_data);
        }
        view_list.set_model(Some(&model_list_of_data));
        let object_to_render_cells: gtk::CellRendererText = gtk::CellRendererText::new();
        object_to_render_cells.set_visible(true);
        let view_column = TreeViewColumn::new();
        view_column.set_expand(true);
        view_column.set_visible(true);
        view_column.set_title("u32");
        view_column.pack_start(&object_to_render_cells, true);
        view_column.add_attribute(&object_to_render_cells, "text", 0);
        view_list.append_column(&view_column);
        // second column
        let object_to_render_cells_2: gtk::CellRendererText = gtk::CellRendererText::new();
        object_to_render_cells_2.set_visible(true);
        let view_column_2 = TreeViewColumn::new();
        view_column_2.set_expand(true);
        view_column_2.set_visible(true);
        view_column_2.set_title("f64");
        view_column_2.pack_start(&object_to_render_cells, true);
        view_column_2.add_attribute(&object_to_render_cells, "text", 1);
        view_list.append_column(&view_column_2);
    }
    view_list.expand_all();
    main_box.add(&view_list);
    window.add(&main_box);
    window.show_all();
    gtk::main();
}
```

I have tried adding `gtk::Type:BaseBoxed` to `types_inside_columns` and then add a boxed `ListStore` to `array_of_data`, but `Box` can not be successfully converted by method `to_value()` to type `ToValue`.

Added:
This program is panicking at runtime:

```
extern crate gtk;
use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::{ComboBox, ListStore, Orientation, TreeView, TreeViewColumn, Window, WindowType};


fn main()
{
    gtk::init().expect("Failed to initialize GTK");
    let window = Window::new(WindowType::Toplevel);
    window.set_position(gtk::WindowPosition::Center);    
    window.set_title("Rust&GTK+3");
    window.set_position(gtk::WindowPosition::Center);
    window.connect_delete_event(|wind, _| {
        let (szerokosc,wysokosc) =  wind.get_size();
        println!("Width {} Height {}",szerokosc,wysokosc);
        // Stop the main loop.
        gtk::main_quit();
        // Let the default handler destroy the window.
        Inhibit(false)
    });
    let main_box = gtk::Box::new(Orientation::Vertical,0);
    let view_list = TreeView::new();
    {
        let types_inside_columns = &[gtk::Type::U32,gtk::Type::F64,gtk::Type::Pointer];
        let model_list_of_data = ListStore::new(types_inside_columns);
        for liczba in 0..10 {
            let model_for_combo = ListStore::new(types_inside_columns);
            let array_of_data = [&(liczba.to_value()) as &ToValue,
            &((liczba as f64 * 1.5).to_value()) as &ToValue,
            ];
            let typ_iter = model_list_of_data.insert_with_values(None,&[0,1],&array_of_data);
            model_list_of_data.set_value(&typ_iter,2, &model_for_combo.to_value() as &gtk::Value);
        }
        view_list.set_model(Some(&model_list_of_data));
        let object_to_render_cells : gtk::CellRendererText = gtk::CellRendererText::new();
        object_to_render_cells.set_visible(true);
        let view_column= TreeViewColumn::new();
        view_column.set_expand(true);
        view_column.set_visible(true);
        view_column.set_title("u32");
        view_column.pack_start(&object_to_render_cells,true);
        view_column.add_attribute(&object_to_render_cells,"text",0);
        view_list.append_column(&view_column);
        //second column
        let object_to_render_cells_2 : gtk::CellRendererCombo = gtk::CellRendererCombo::new();
        let view_column_2 = TreeViewColumn::new();
        view_column_2.set_expand(true);
        view_column_2.set_visible(true);
        view_column_2.set_title("f64");
        view_column_2.pack_start(&object_to_render_cells_2,true);
        view_column_2.add_attribute(&object_to_render_cells_2,"text",1);
        view_list.append_column(&view_column_2);
    }
    view_list.expand_all();
    main_box.add(&view_list);
    window.add(&main_box);
    window.show_all();
    gtk::main();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Type problems

If you want to store a `gtk::ListStore` in another `gtk::ListStore`, you don't specify `gtk::Type::Pointer`, you'll need to make use of the last variant, [`gtk::Type::Other(usize)`](http://gtk-rs.org/docs/glib/types/enum.Type.html). You can get the type of `gtk::ListStore` with [`ToValue::to_value_type`](http://gtk-rs.org/docs/gtk/trait.ToValue.html#tymethod.to_value_type) at runtime. I sadly could not find a method to do this at compile-time as the type number changes.

```
let model = ListStore::new(&[Type::U8]);
println!("{:?}", model.to_value_type()); // Other(139977306752544)
println!("{:?}", model.to_value()); // Value(((GtkListStore*) 0x7f4f01b9a060))
// get type at runtime
let liststore_type = model.to_value_type();
let model = ListStore::new(&[Type::U32, Type::F64, liststore_type]);
```

Now you can insert your sub-model as you wanted to do with `ToValue::to_value`.

#### Using `gtk::CellRendererCombo`

However, you wrote that you want to use combo boxes in a row, possibly for editing a number. For this, you do not need nested `gtk::ListStore`. You need a model for the `gtk::TreeView` and another for the options.

```
let model_list_of_data = ListStore::new(&[gtk::Type::U32, gtk::Type::String]);
let model_for_combo = ListStore::new(&[gtk::Type::String]);


for liczba in 0..10 {
    let integer = liczba.to_value();
    let float = format!("{}", liczba as f64 * 1.5).to_value();

    model_list_of_data.insert_with_values(None, &[0, 1], &[&integer, &float]);
    model_for_combo.insert_with_values(None, &[0], &[&float]);
}

// code for first column not changed

let object_to_render_cells_2: gtk::CellRendererCombo = gtk::CellRendererCombo::new();
object_to_render_cells_2.set_visible(true);
object_to_render_cells_2.set_property_editable(true);
// use the combo model for the options
object_to_render_cells_2.set_property_model(Some(&model_for_combo.upcast()));
// display the options of the first column in the combo model
object_to_render_cells_2.set_property_text_column(0);
let view_column_2 = TreeViewColumn::new();
view_column_2.set_expand(true);
view_column_2.set_visible(true);
view_column_2.set_title("f64");
view_column_2.pack_start(&object_to_render_cells_2, false);
// the data for each row is in the second column in the tree model
view_column_2.add_attribute(&object_to_render_cells_2, "text", 1);
view_list.append_column(&view_column_2);
```

You might have noticed that I used strings instead of plain floats. This has two reasons:

1. Using `format!`, unnecessary zeros are not included in the output
2. With plain floats, gtk will display the combo, but will crash if you click on one

[image: screenshot]